# Import products into odoo (openerp)

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I would like to import some products into odoo/openerp for the point of sale module. Howewer I have a category called "Chalet" which is not found during import. Where can I find the external id of the product category?

This is the .csv which I would like to import:

```
    External ID,Name,Internal Reference,Category/External ID,Can be Expensed,Can be Purchased,Can be Sold,Sale Price,Cost,Supply Method,Product Type,Procurement Method
    AR1,Arni ,AR1,Chalet,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,0,0,Buy,Service,Make to Stock
    AU9,Ausbi 1 ,AU9,Chalet,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,0,0,Buy,Service,Make to Stock
```

This is the error message I get:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier way would be to go to product categories, look for the id of the category Chalet (open form with it and in address you will see id=X), then replace in your csv Chalet with this id and when importing don't go with external id but with database id for category. Most likely what happened here is that you have never exported category 'Chalet' so the external id is not known - another approach would be exporting category, checking external id and putting it instead of name.

Comment: Great, I just created a sample product with the wanted category and exportet it into a csv file. this worked fine! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You must check if a product category 'Chalet' exist in product categories. If yes, if the category 'Chalet' is a child of another category like 'All products', maybe you should put 'All products/Chalet' as product category in the csv file.

Comment: I set the parent category to "Others" and tryed it with "Others/Chalet" but it didn't work. Any other ideas? Where could I find the ID of the Category chalet??

Answer (score 0):

You can find the product category in the URL when viewing the category.

1. Goto: Sales>Configuration>Product Categories & Attributes>Product Categories
2. Open your category *Chalet*
3. Check the URL shown in your browser.  Should look like `http://yourodooaddress.com/web?#id=3&view_type=form&model=product.category&menu_id=119&action=119`
4. In this case the category I was viewing was **id=3**, yours will of course be different

EDIT: I previously thought id-119 was the category id, but it was actually the first id= in the url string.  In my case ***id=3***